# how to get this two date value from this one value?

Tags: php, html

[image]

```
"<"input type="text" value="13-03-2016 - 13-04-2016" name="date">"
```

How to get this two date from this one value ? like below

```
$date1=$_POST['13-03-2016'];
$date2=$_POST['13-04-2016'];
```

Comment: $date = explode(' - ',$_POST['date']); and you get array.

Answer (score 0):

Currently your string is looks like `"Y-m-d - Y-m-d"`. You can split this string by [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) command by `-` separator.

So you can use this code:

```
list($date1, $date2) = explode(' - ', $_POST['date']);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Your answer is currently flagged "low quality" and might eventually be removed.

Comment: I've added some explanation, but this code works before this addition:)

Comment: Thanks, I get this is rather trivial, but not everyone might understand it :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access passing the wrong parameter to POST method!, the name of your input is 'date', then you should access $_POST[date]

You could use 2 inputs! (use type="date").

Try this:

```
<input type="date" name="start">
<input type="date" name="end">
```

Then.. after submit your form you can access $_POST[start] and $_POST[end]

Comment: hi thx for ur comments ........i know the method .
im just added there two value for example to show.
i want 1 input field in 2 different date and get in individually date format.
i hope u understand .......